# Populating adapters in for loops android

Tags: java, android

Hi I have an `SeparatedListAdapter` that I'm trying to populate. I have an `JSONObject` of multiple `JSONArray`s that contain `JSONObject`s of people. I am trying to loop through `JSONObject` and create a header for each `JSONArray` I then want to loop through each `JSONArray` and add an item to the list and get the name of the person.

At the moment its creating the headers correctly but it loops through and keeps adding every name to the list from every `JSONObject` I just need it to add the ones from that `JSONArray`.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"Contacts": //JSONObject
  {
    "B"://JSONArray..
    [
        {"first_name":sdfsdf,"last_name":900,"Number":1368349}, 
        {"first_name":adsdfd,"last_name":1900,"Number":136856},  
         {"first_name":adglkhdofg,"last_name":600,"Number":136845}
   ],
  "C":[
         {"first_name":alkghoi,"last_name":900,"Number":1368349},
         {"first_name":wetete,"last_name":1900,"Number":136856}, 
         {"first_name":dfhtfh,"last_name":600,"Number":136845}
     ]
      .....//and so on.. 
     }


}
```

Heres my for loop so far:

```
JSONObject singleContactDetails;

                    contactName = new ArrayList<String>();
                    accessLevel = new ArrayList<String>();
                    imageURL = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray namesArray = new JSONArray();
                    SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(getActivity());  

                    for (int t=0; t< headerStrings.length(); t++){

                        JSONArray contactsArray = contacts.getJSONArray(headerStrings.getString(t));
                        Log.v("CAA", "contactsArray = " + contactsArray.length());
                        for (int i=0; i<contactsArray.length(); i++){

                            try {
                                singleContactDetails = contactsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = singleContactDetails.getString("first_name") + " " + singleContactDetails.getString("last_name");
                                contactName.add(name);

                                Log.v("CAA", "namesArray" + namesArray); 
                                accessLevel.add(singleContactDetails.getString("access_level"));
                                imageURL.add(singleContactDetails.getString("filename"));




                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }   


                        }   


                    adapter.addSection(headerStrings.getString(t), new ContactArrayAdapter (getActivity(),R.layout.document_cell,contactName,accessLevel,imageURL, bgColor, gilSans));  

                    Log.v("Main", "contacts.getJSONArray(headerStrings.getString(t)) = " + contacts.getJSONArray(headerStrings.getString(t)));      

                    }
```

What it outputs is this because there are 6 objects altogether but it adds all the objects to each section:

```
B
name
name
name
name
name
name

C
name
name
name
name
name
name
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
B
name
name
name

C
name
name
name
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `headerStrings`

Comment: @VivekWarde just an array of strings from the arrays so B,C,D etc